# In SQL, how do I get the sum of a column grouped by ID where only the most recent date is selected?

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I am working with a table like this:

| ID | Quantity1 | Quantity2 | Quantity3 | Quantity4 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 100 | 0 | 200 | 300 | 3/1/2020 |
| 101 | 300 | 80 | 2200 | 400 | 3/1/2020 |
| 101 | 100 | 0 | 200 | 300 | 1/1/2020 |
| 101 | 20 | 0 | 6 | 50 | 1/1/2020 |
| 102 | 1000 | 0 | 200 | 300 | 3/1/2020 |
| 102 | 600 | 80 | 2200 | 400 | 3/1/2020 |
| 102 | 900 | 0 | 200 | 300 | 1/1/2020 |
| 102 | 400 | 30 | 65 | 90 | 1/1/2020 |

I want to write an SQL query that will give me the sums of the quantity columns by ID but taking only the entries from the most recent date. My expected output is:

| ID | Quantity1 | Quantity2 | Quantity3 | Quantity4 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 400 | 80 | 2400 | 700 | 3/1/2020 |
| 102 | 1600 | 80 | 2400 | 700 | 3/1/2020 |

I know how to sum entire columns by ID, but not with the added wrinkle of needing to do it by max date. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select id, sum(quantity1), sum(quantity2), sum(quantity3), sum(quantity4),
       date
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.id = t.id
               )
group by id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by both Id and Date(if you expect 2 or more records for a single date).
Along with below examples, you could also use Row_number().

with temp as(
select 12 as id,45 as quantity1, '2021-02-19' as date
union all
select 22 as id, 88 as quantity1 , '2019-12-12' as date
union all
select 12 as id , 10 as quantity1,'2021-02-19' as date )

approach 1: select id,sum(quantity1), date from temp
group by id, date
order by date desc
limit 1 (-- or top 1 )

approach 2:
select id,sum(quantity1), date from temp
where date=(select max(date) from temp)
group by id, date